# How to write recursive javascript function to achieve desired output

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need some help in writing recursive javascript function to achieve something but I am really struggling to achieve that. Can someone please help me or guide me on this.

I have nested tree something like this, Group1 has child Group2 and Group2 has child Group3. Group3 has no child.

```
[
  {
    name: "Group1",
    children: [{
      name: "Group2",
      children: [{
        name: "Group3"
        children: []
      }],
    }]
  },
 {
   name: "Group5",
   children: [],
 },
 {
  name: "Group6",
  children: [],
 },
 {
  name: "Group7",
  children: [{
    name: "Group 10",
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Group2'
            children: [{
        name: "Group3"
        children: []
      }], 
        }
    ]
  }],
 }
]
```

If I search Group2, function should return all parents and child elements separately in an array. How can I achieve this.

Example:

Input: "Group2"

Output:

```
[
   {
      name: "Group1",
      children:[
         {
            name:"Group2",
            children :[
               {
                  name:"Group3",
                  children:[]
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      name:"Group2",
      children: [
         {
            name:"Group3",
            children:[]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      name:"Group3",
      children:[]
   },
   {
      name:"Group7",
      children :[
         {
            name:"Group10",
            children:[
               {
                  name:"Group2",
                  children: [
                     {
                        name:"Group3",
                        children :[]
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
   },    
   {
     name:"Group10",
     children:[
            {
               name:"Group2",
               children:[
                  {
                     name:"Group3",
                     children":[]
                  }
               ]
            }
      ]
   }
]
```

If I search 'Group2', it should give me complete node separately in a list in which this term exist. For example: 'Group 2' is child of 'Group 1' so complete node tree should be in list [Group1, Group2, Group3] and then 'Group2' is also child of 'Group10', which is also child of 'Group7', so combining complete family for this [Group7, Group10, Group2, Group3]. So complete output should be like all distinct nodes [Group1, Group2, Group3, Group7, Group10 ]. Is this making sense??

Any help will be appreciated.

I was writing code something like this, this works but don't know how to do it better.

```
  const groups = this.props.groups;
  const filter = (group: Group) => group.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm);
  if (this.state.searchTerm !== '') {
      groups = groups.filter(filter);
      groups = this.groupHierarchy(groups);
  }

  private groupHierarchy = (filteredGroups: Group[]) => {
    const groups: Group[] = filteredGroups;
    groups.map((filteredGroup: Group) =>
      this.addAllChildren(filteredGroup, groups));
    groups.map((filteredGroup: Group) =>
      this.addAllParents(filteredGroup, groups));
    return groups;
  }

  private addAllChildren = (filteredGroup: Group, childGroups: Group[]) => {
    const groups = childGroups;
    if (filteredGroup.children) {
      filteredGroup.children.map((child: Group) => {
        if (!groups.find(a => a.id === child.id)) {
          groups.push(child);
        }
        this.addAllChildren(child, groups);
      });
    }
    return groups;
  }

  private addAllParents = (filteredGroup: Group, parentGroups: Group[]) => {
    const groups = parentGroups;
    if (filteredGroup.parent && filteredGroup.parent.id) {

      const parentGroup = this.props.groups.find(group => group.id === filteredGroup.parent!.id)!;
      if (!groups.find(a => a.id === parentGroup.id)) {
        groups.push(parentGroup);
      }
      this.addAllParents(parentGroup, groups);
    }
    return groups;
  }
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code that you need help with.

Comment: Please pardon me, I have posted my code.

Comment: do you want only the direct parent? or all parents?

Comment: All parents means complete node tree for that search term.

Comment: is `'Group2'` the same as `'Group 2'`? please use an example with unique identifier.

Comment: Yes my bad, I have updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version makes generic functions for checking whether a node or one of its descendants matches a generic predicate and, using that, for collecting all the nodes matching a predicate along with all their ancestors and children.

Using the latter, we write a simple function which accepts a target name, and returns a function which will find all the nodes with a `name` property that matches the target, along with all their ancestors and children:

```js
const hasMatch = (pred) => ({children = [], ...rest}) =>
  pred (rest) || children .some (hasMatch (pred))

const collectFamily = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (
    x => pred(x) 
      ? [x, ...(x.children || [])] 
    : hasMatch (pred) (x) 
      ? [x, ...collectFamily (pred) (x.children || [])]
    : []
  )

const collectFamilyByName = (target) => 
  collectFamily((({name}) => name == target))

const log = (fn) => (inputs) => // JSON.stringify avoids StackOverflow console artifacts
  inputs .forEach (o => console .log (JSON .stringify (fn (o), null, 2)))

const inputs = [
  [{name: "Group 1", children: [{name: "Group 2", children: [{name: "Group 3", children: []}]}]}, {name: "Group 5", children: []}],
  [{name: "Group 1", children: [{name: "Group 2", children: [{name: "Group 3", children: []}]}]}, {name: "Group 5", children: [{name: 'Group 2', children: []}]}],
]

log (collectFamilyByName ('Group 2')) (inputs)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I have two example cases.  The first is the one from the question.  The second, following a comment on another answer, adds to the `'Group 5'` object a child of `'Group 2'`, and it is collected as I believe you wish.

The code is fairly simple, but I see two potential disadvantages.  First, it recurs separately over the tree for testing and collecting.  I'm sure there is a relatively clean way to combine them, but I don't see it right away.  Second, this will fail to collect descendants of children of nodes that also have the right name.  It stops at their children.  Again, I imagine there's a quick fix for that, but I'm not seeing it at the moment.

### Update - code explanation

A comment implied that this code could use explanation.  Here's an attempt

We look first at the simplest function, the main one, `collectFamilyByName`:

```js
const collectFamilyByName = (target) => 
  collectFamily((({name}) => name == target))
```

This function takes a `target` string and calls `collectFamily` passing a function that uses that `target`.  We don't know yet what `collectFamily` will do; we just know that it takes a predicate function (one returning `true` or `false`) and returns to us a new function.

We could have written this in a few different ways.  Here's one alternative:

```js
const testMatch = function (target) {
  return function (element) {
    return element.name == target
  }
}

const collectFamilyByName = function (target) {
  return collectFamily (testMatch (target))
}
```

which by simple substitution would be equivalent to

```js
const collectFamilyByName = function (target) {
  return collectFamily (function (element) {
    return element.name == target
  })
}
```

By using more modern arrow functions for the inner function, this would become

```js
const collectFamilyByName = function (target) {
  return collectFamily (element => element.name == target)
}
```

and then for the outer one:

```js
const collectFamilyByName = (target) =>
  collectFamily (element => element.name == target)
```

And finally, we can use parameter destructuring to remove the `element` parameter, like this:

```js
const collectFamilyByName = (target) =>
  collectFamily (({name}) => name == target)
```

Now, in order to understand `collectFamily`, we have to understand `hasMatch`.  Let's expand this again to ES5 style:

```js
const hasMatch = function (pred) {
  return function (element) {
    return pred (element) || 
           element .children .some (function (child) {
             return hasMatch (pred) (child)
           })
  }
}
```

This is standard ES5 code, almost, but not quite, equivalent to the version above.  Here we accept a predicate and return a function which accepts an element and returns a boolean.  It will be true if the predicate returns `true` for the element, or, recurring on the element's children, if `hasMatch` passed the same predicate and then passed each child, returns true on any of them, using [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

This is simplified into the above again using arrow functions and parameter destructuring.  The one difference is that the ES5 function applies the predicate to the entire object and the ES6 one applies it to a copy of the object that doesn't include `children`.  If this is not desired, we could skip the parameter destructuring here, but I think it usually makes sense to do it this way.

Finally, the main function is `collectFamily`, which looks like this:

```js
const collectFamily = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (
    x => pred(x) 
      ? [x, ...(x.children || [])] 
    : hasMatch (pred) (x) 
      ? [x, ...collectFamily (pred) (x.children || [])]
    : []
  )
```

I won't go through the ES6 -> ES5 exercise here.  It works just the same as in the other two.  Instead, let's look at [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

- **`flatMap`** is an operation on arrays that works much like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), except that it expects the function to return *an array* of objects on every call, which it then combines into a single array.

  ```js
  [10, 20, 30] .flatMap ((n) => [n, n + 1, n + 2])
  //=> [10, 11, 12, 20, 21, 22, 30, 31, 32]
  ```
- **the spread syntax** uses the token `...` to spread the contents of an array
  (or an object, not relevant here) into another array.  So if `xs` held `[1, 2, 3]` then `[5, 10, ...xs, 20]` would yield `[5, 10, 1, 2, 3, 20]`.

Knowing these, we can understand `collectFamily`.  It accepts a predicate (which we already know we saw will be one that matches on objects whose `name` property has the same value as our target value) and returns a function which takes an array of objects.  It calls flatMap on this array, passing a function, so we know that that function must return an array of values, given one element in the original array.

If I were to rewrite this, I might lay it out a little differently to make the body of that function slightly more clear, perhaps like this:

```js
const collectFamily = (pred) => (xs) => 
  xs .flatMap (
    (x) => 
      pred (x) 
        ? [x, ...(x .children || [])] 
      : hasMatch (pred) (x) 
        ? [x, ...collectFamily (pred) (x .children || [])]
      : []
  )
```

And the function, which is passed an array value with parameter name `x`, would have this body:

```js
      pred (x) 
        ? [x, ...(x.children || [])] 
      : hasMatch (pred) (x) 
        ? [x, ...collectFamily (pred) (x.children || [])]
      : []
```

We return one of three different values.

In the first case, if the predicate matches our current value (again, remember in this case, that's if the `name` property of `x` matches the target, such as `'Group 2'`), then we return an array including `x` and all of its children.  We use the `|| []` so that if `x .children` were not defined, we would still have an iterable object to spread into our array.  It doesn't matter for the sample data as supplied, but it's useful in many cases.

In the second case, if we have a match somewhere nested more deeply, as reported by `hasMatch`, we return an array including this node, and all the results found by recursively calling `collectFamily` with the same predicate against the list of children (again, defaulted to an empty array if they don't exist.)

And in the third case, if neither of those is true, we simply return an empty array.

---

So that's how this works.  There's no magic here, but if you're new to the language, some of the more modern features may seem a bit obscure.  I promise, though, that with a little practice, they'll become second-nature.  They make for much simpler code, and, once you're used to the syntax, they seem to me much easier to read as well.

Comment: Thank you very much for the efforts. But sadly I couldn't understand solution as I am relatively new to these technologies.

Comment: @Sagar: Added a long explanation of the code.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach with a short circuit on find.

To get all parents, the function contains another parameter for visited parents.

```js
const
    getFromTree = (tree, name, parents = []) => {
        let result;
        tree.some(node => result = node.name === name
            ? [...parents, node, ...node.children]
            : getFromTree(node.children, name, [...parents, node])
        );
        return result;
    },
    tree = [{ name: "Group 1", children: [{ name: "Group 2", children: [{ name: "Group 3", children: [] }] }] }, { name: "Group 5", children: [] }];

console.log(getFromTree(tree, "Group 1"));
console.log(getFromTree(tree, "Group 2"));
console.log(getFromTree(tree, "Group 3"));
console.log(getFromTree(tree, "Group 5"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nice but this won't work correct in all cases like Group5  node also contains Group2 but this function would not return Group5.

Comment: `'Group 5'` has no parent.

Comment: No I am saying suppose if Group 5 has child Group 2 , then this method would not return Group5 in the list.

Comment: Not only All parents  but all children also should be in the list. Please see output for Group 2 search term.

Comment: please add the wanted result in the question. maybe a different tree (more depth) would help alogn with the wanted result of it.

Comment: Just keeping it in a simple words, I want all parents and children of node in a separate list for which search term matches. So there can many other nodes as well.. I am updating question in a bit.

Comment: I have updated question. can you please have a look at it now. Thank you.